# How do I set Signed Date with the last Signer without Routing Order?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm facing a problem and to me is very hard to understand why something so simple is so hard to find a solution. Basically I want so set a Signed Date in each document (contained in the envelope) when the last signer complete the process.

I have this documents and signers

Documents: Doc A, Doc B, Doc C

Signers: Signer 1, Signer 2, Signer 3

Now the combination

Signers by documents:

Doc A: Signer 1, Signer 2 and Signer 3

Doc B: Signer 1 and Signer 2

Doc C: Signer 2 and Signer 3

So, the idea is create an envelope with all this information and without setting the Routing Order I would like to set a Signed Date in each document when the last signer (I don't know which one was) make the sign.

There is some magical way to do that?

I will appreciate any tip/help :)

PS: This is my first question, so sorry if i'm doing something wrong.

```
{
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "signer1@yopmail.com",
        "name": "Signer 1",
        "recipientId": 1,
        "tabs": {
          "dateSignedTabs": [
            {
              "font": "Calibri",
              "fontSize": "Size9",
              "bold": "true",
              "anchorString": "Signer1 Signed Date",
              "anchorUnits": "pixels",
              "anchorYOffset": "-2", 
              "anchorXOffset": "-5"
            }
          ],
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
                "anchorString": "Signer 1",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "anchorYOffset": "10", 
                "anchorXOffset": "-40"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "email": "signer2@yopmail.com",
        "name": "Signer 2",
        "recipientId": 2,
        "tabs": {
          "dateSignedTabs": [
            {
              "font": "Calibri",
              "fontSize": "Size9",
              "bold": "true",
              "anchorString": "Signer2 Signed Date",
              "anchorUnits": "pixels",
              "anchorYOffset": "-2", 
              "anchorXOffset": "-5"
            }
          ],
          "signHereTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "Signer 2",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "anchorYOffset": "10", 
                "anchorXOffset": "-40"
              }
            ]
          }
      },
      {
        "email": "signer3@yopmail.com",
        "name": "Signer 3",
        "recipientId": 3,
        "tabs": {
          "dateSignedTabs": [
            {
              "font": "Calibri",
              "fontSize": "Size9",
              "bold": "true",
              "anchorString": "Signer3 Signed Date",
              "anchorUnits": "pixels",
              "anchorYOffset": "-2", 
              "anchorXOffset": "-5"
            }
          ],
          "signHereTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "Signer 3",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "anchorYOffset": "10", 
                "anchorXOffset": "-40"
              }
            ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document Call",
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "Doc A.pdf",
      "documentBase64": <Document1_Base64>
    },
    {
      "documentId": "2",
      "name": "Doc B.pdf",
      "documentBase64": <Document2_Base64>
    },
    {
      "documentId": "3",
      "name": "Doc C.pdf",
      "documentBase64": <Document3_Base64>
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}

POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes
```

Using REST API v2.1 I create an envelope with the payload code as example.

As you can see I don't want to use Routing Order, so, each signers has its own dateSignedTabs witch for mi is OK, but I want so get the date of the last signer to put it at the begin of the Document, thats is my real deal.

Comment: can you share your code? I'm not clear what is your issue

Comment: Thanks @InbarGazit for you response, I added a code that I use to try solve my issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `dateSigned` tab belongs to a specific signer recipient. So you have a couple of options:

1. Use a routing order. Then the `dateSigned` of the last person will be the date of the last signer.
2. On the signing page of the document add verbiage such as "This agreement was finalized on the date of the last signature" -- followed by the three signatures and three `dateSigned` tabs. Consult a lawyer, I'm sure your goal can be accomplished by contract language. Here is an [example by a contract writer](https://www.adamsdrafting.com/having-parties-date-their-signatures/#:%7E:text=This%20agreement%20will%20become%20effective,the%20date%20of%20this%20agreement.).
3. You can add more programming to add an "effective date" field with the date the last person signed. See below.

### To add an "effective date" of the last signer

1. Set all of your signers to routing order 1. Since they're all the same routing order, this is the same as no routing order for the enveloper signers.
2. Add a fake embedded signer as routing order 2. Something like "System" with email address "system_signer@example.com". Since this is an embedded signer, they will not be sent any email.
3. Add a webhook either at the account (Connect) or envelope (eventNotification) level. You can receive the webhook behind the firewall with no firewall changes by using an intermediate PaaS system. See my [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhook-listeners-part-4)
4. The webhook notifies your app when the envelope has been "sent" to the system signer. Correct the envelope: set the value of your "effective date" tab (a text tab) to the current date. And delete the "system" signer. The envelope will now proceed to completion.
5. Success.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to perform this idea. But to be honest don't you think that something so simple like a "Effective date" is so complicated without Routing Order?

Comment: Hi Larry, i I'm kind of stuck in point 4, I am trying to set the value for the "effective date" using tab (a text tab) but it seams that is not working. :(

Comment: Hi @MarianoDiez -- please open a new question on StackOverflow. StackOverflow is designed to have one question and one answer per post.