# docusign to populate an effective date with of the date of the last signature

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign to have contracts signed by various parties.

I am looking for a way to populate my contracts with an `effective date` field, I don't know a priori the order in which the parties will sign (i.e. I don't know who will sign last), but I couldn't find a placeholder to populate such field.

has anyone got a workaround for it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If the sender of the document used the routing order feature to control who will be the last signer, then just use the `dateSigned` tab (field) type with the last signer.

If the signers are at the same routing level, then see my prior answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63651154/64904